# Difference between two ways of returning a vector in C++ by a function

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, stdvector

Given the following functions, i.e., params() and mutable_params():

```
std::vector<int> params_;

std::vector<int>& params() {
return params_;
}
std::vector<int>* mutable_params() {
return &params_;
}
```

what is the difference between vec1 and vec2 in the following expressions:

```
std::vector<int> vec1=params();
std::vector<int> vec2=mutable_params();
```

Comment: Well, one difference is that `vec2` line will not compile.

Comment: `std::vector<int> vec2=mutable_params()` won't compile, you might want `std::vector<int> vec2=*mutable_params()` instead.

Comment: The 2 ways allow to mutate the vector, so, naming is wrong... `ByRef`/`ByPointer` would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

vec2 will not compile. If you change it to `std::vector<int>* vec2=mutable_params();`, then it will compile.

The difference between the two functions, is that `params()` returns a reference to the vector, while `mutable_params()` returns a pointer to the vector *but both will be mutable*!

A more interesting example is the difference between those two variables:

```
std::vector<int> v_copy = params();
std::vector<int>& v_ref = params();
```

In this case `v_copy`copies the entire vector, while `v_ref` is a reference to the original vector, and therefore lets you change the original vector.

If you want the `params()` function to return a non-mutable reference, you must change its declaration to `const std::vector<int>& params();`

Comment: Thanks. So what is the difference between these two functions then:
std::vector<int>& params1() {
return params_;
} 
and
std::vector<int> params2() {
return params_;
}

Comment: @JohnBM `std::vector<int>& params1()` returns a (mutable) reference to the vector, while `std::vector<int> params2()` returns a copy of the vector.